# Show that the term $xy+1$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, fermat-numbers

> Let $F_k$ denote the $k$th Fermat number $2^{2^k}+1$.  If $$A=\{F_{2n}, \ F_{2n+2}, \ F_{2n+4}, \ 4F_{2n+1}F_{2n+2}F_{2n+3}\},$$ then I want to show that for $x,y\in A$ with $x\neq y$ the term $xy+1$ is a perfect square.

$$$$

We have that $$F_M=2^{2^M}+1 \ \text{ and } \ F_N=2^{2^N}+1$$ Then $$F_MF_N+1=\left (2^{2^M}+1\right )\cdot \left (2^{2^N}+1\right )+1=2^{2^M+2^N}+2^{2^M}+2^{2^N}+1$$

Do we have to substitute the values for $M$ and $N$ to see that we get a perfect square or do we have to do something else?

Comment: Well, you have to look at every possible pair of elements from $A$.  There are four elements in $A$ so there are $\binom 42=6$ possible pairs.  Of course, some pairs are similar to some others.

Comment: Last term of expression for $F_MF_N+1$ is $+2$.

Comment: If $M, N \ge 1$, $F_M F_N+1 \equiv 2 \mod 4$, so this is never a perfect square.

Comment: So you mean that the statement is not true? @RobertIsrael

Comment: Yes, the statement is not true.

Comment: Take $n=1$, $F_{2n}=17, F_{2n}+2=19 $, 
$17\times 19+1=18^2$. I think there must be a typo. Because it seems like there is SOMETHING to see here just not the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about Fibonacci numbers.

**Hint**
Use the equation: 
$F_{n+1}^2= F_{n}F_{n+2} + (-1)^n$